# Parse question mark as normal character after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

So this may sound weird, however I currently have mod_rewrite set-up to pass 2 variables through.

```
RewriteRule ^profiel/(.*)$ index.php?p=profiel&user=$1
```

In the second var (&user=), it passes a username which is retrieved through GET in PHP. However, some of the usernames can have question marks in them. However if this is the case, the question mark won't be passed to the GET variable. (For example: "www.example.com/profiel/whoami?" ends up as just "whoami" instead of "whoami?")

I honestly don't know how to solve this problem. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule by capturing your values directly from `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(profiel)/(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^profiel/ index.php?p=%1&user=%2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. I'm quite interested, as I'm not that great with mod_rewrite rules, what does the above exactly do? I'd love to know!

Comment: [Check this good tutorial](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php) We are capturing value directly from THE_REQUEST variable here. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function `urlencode` to encode the username. For example, `whoami?` will become `whoami%3F`. So your url will become `www.example.com/profiel/whoami%3F`

Then to retrieve your username, you can use `urldecode`.

Here's the documentation on both function:

- [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)
- [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: $_GET automaticly does urldecode. However, that isn't the problem. User inputted data (so not encoded, simply a question mark) was the problem.