# Parse question mark as normal character after mod_rewrite (2)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

So some time ago, I asked the following question on StackOverflow:
[Parse question mark as normal character after mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658832/parse-question-mark-as-normal-character-after-mod-rewrite)

This solved the problem as I described it, however now I have a smiliar issue, with a different name. This time, the question mark is in front.

For example: "www.example.com/profiel/?myusername" ends up empty instead of "?myusername".

Current .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^profiel$ index.php?p=profiel
#RewriteRule ^profiel/(.*)$ index.php?p=profiel&user=$1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(profiel)/(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^profiel/ index.php?p=%1&user=%2 [L,NC]
```

So with the previous fix, I simply moved the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How should `www.example.com/profiel/?myusername` be rewritten to internally? (btw I didn't downvote your question)

Comment: Everything after profiel/ is the full username.So this could be "?myusername", "my?username" or "myusername?" of which the last one has been fixed in my previous question.

Comment: @anubhava, for some reason it refused to work for me. Let me provide you with the full htaccess lines concerning this page. Added it to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(profiel)/(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile1 index.php?p=%1&user=%2 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^profiel/?$ index.php?p=profiel [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you once again. Such a stupid mistake, really should get more into htaccess and mod_rewrite. Problem has been solved!