# Keep question mark on $_GET with rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I've found [this interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658832/parse-question-mark-as-normal-character-after-mod-rewrite?noredirect=1&lq=1) on making the question mark symbol appear on $_GET variable after using rewrite rules.

However, as much as I've tried to accomplish this myself, I didn't quite understand how it works to have the same result on my website.

Here's my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This basically allows me to route users to specific places without hard coding each page on my htaccess file, so if a user goes to /about/contact page, he's actually going to index.php?uri=/about/contact.

The problem is that sometimes I WANT the question mark to be kept in $_GET. Let's say a topic title of "What's up?" then my url would search for a topic like /topic/what-s-up? and would match with what-s-up? in the database. But, right now, my $_GET variable stores just "what-s-up" (without the "?") and my database still stores "what-s-up?" (with the "?"), which would say that there's no topic with that title when there actually is.

How can I keep the question mark so /topic/what-s-up? still translates to /topic/what-s-up? in the query string?

**EDIT: FULL .HTACCESS FILE FOR TEST PURPOSES**

```
Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `?` is a reserved character in URL's and should not be used as part of a slug

Comment: @naththedeveloper right, but what if I still want to keep it?

Comment: Use: %3F in url to get it as `?`... `urlencode` , so your url `/topic/what-s-up?` would be: `/topic/what-s-up%3F`

Comment: @Ultrazz008 this solves as far as links are concerned, but not when a user types it directly in the url.

Comment: I tried sending `test.php?asd=?red?` and the output was `Array ( [asd] => ?red? )` :p or the rewrite rule destroyes it ?

Comment: @Ultrazz008 seems like a rewrite rule, try adding the full .htaccess file into your test page. I've updated the question with it. Then output $_GET["uri"] or the query string.

Comment: What if you want to support a genuine query string on your site such as `example.com/search?q=findit`? Do you still want to pass full `search?q=findit` to database?

Comment: @anubhava I want to keep the url as `/search/findit`. But if a user actually searches for "whatisthis?" I wanna still be able to have `/search/whatisthis?` and have the $_GET["uri"] to show `/search/whatisthis?` instead of `/search/whatisthis` (without the "?"). Then I just explode it by `/` and get the part I want to make the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your rule to this to capture optional `?` in `uri` parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]*\??\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Since we want `?` also to be captured we are using `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` since pattern in `RewriteRule` only matches REQUEST_URI. Since we are capturing value from `RewriteCond` hence we are using `%1` instead of `$1` as back-reference.

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents complete original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Hello, you've totally nailed it! Would be nice, anyways, to provide an explanation of what this Cond does and why have you changed `$` to `%` in `index.php?uri=\´ part. I appreciate your effort into answering this question. I'll mark as solved, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I know its late, but i used php [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) to pass the question mark, as it converts ? to %3F